# Spacing between inserted image and caption in R markdown

Tags: r-markdown, knitr

I want to adjust the spacing between an inserted image and the caption (HTML output). The default output in latex/PDF looks nice. But the space in html is way too little (see the attached image).

[image]

I searched around but found no solution so far.  I would imagine that this can be solved by adjusting the margin of the image, margin of the caption, or adding vertical space, but really need some guidance on how. Any suggestion is appreciated!